# Shape memory alloy fibers with low Young's Modulus?

Tags: actuator

I am wondering if there exist any species of shape memory alloy fibers with low Young's Modulus at room temperature, for an application I'm working on.  So far I've played with Flexinol, but it is a bit too stiff.  I know Nitinol has a Young's Modulus of ~30-40 GPa.  I am wondering if there exist softer fibers - I'm interested ones that might be at around ~10 GPa, ~1GPa, and < 1GPa, if they exist.

Beyond other materials, is there any procedure to make Nitinol naturally softer?

Comment: Well, I mean, Nitinol is used as an actuator in circuits; you pass current through it and it actuates, but if you think I'll have better luck over there I can post there.